# Is there a way to decorate multiple classes - some with extended interfaces - with a single decorator class?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, decorator

I'm working on some simple custom pipelining code, and I wish to implement a caching decorator over both `IProcessor` and `IProcessorComposite` – the latter is the interface for the pipeline classes (not shown here), which contain and execute multiple processors.

But `IProcessorComposite` extends `IProcessor` with `Add()` and `Remove()` methods, both of which should be exposed through the decorator...

Is there a way I can do this with a single decorator class? Or what is generally the best DRY approach in situations like this?

Should I just implement the widest interface, and throw exceptions when methods are called on decorators decorating classes with narrower interfaces?

Part of the (unfinished) code I'm working on:

```
interface IProcessor<TIn, TOut>
{
    TOut Process(TIn input, TOut output = default(TOut));
}

interface IProcessorComposite<TIn, TOut> : IProcessor<TIn, TOut>
{
    IProcessorComposite<TIn, TOut> Add(IProcessor<TIn, TOut> processor);
    IProcessorComposite<TIn, TOut> Remove(IProcessor<TIn, TOut> processor);
}

interface IProcessorCache<TIn, TOut>
{
    void Remove(TIn key);
    void Add(TIn key, TOut value);
    void Update(TIn key, TOut newValue);
    void Flush();
    IProcessor<TIn, TOut> Processor { get; }
}

class ProcessorCache<TIn, TOut> : IProcessor<TIn, TOut>, IProcessorCache<TIn, TOut>
{
    protected Dictionary<TIn, TOut> _cache = new Dictionary<TIn, TOut>();
    public IProcessor<TIn, TOut> Processor => _decorated;
    protected IProcessor<TIn, TOut> _decorated;

    public TOut Process(TIn input, TOut output = default(TOut))
    {
        TOut value = _cache.GetValueOrDefault(input);

        // If not cached, get fresh one and cache it
        if (value.Equals(default(TOut)))
        {
            value = _decorated.Process(input, output);
            Add(input, value);
        }

        output = value;
        return output;
    }

    public ProcessorCache(IProcessor<TIn, TOut> decorated)
    {
        _decorated = decorated;
    }

    public void Remove(TIn key)
    {
        _cache.Remove(key);
    }

    public void Add(TIn key, TOut value)
    {
        _cache.Add(key, value);
    }

    public void Update(TIn key, TOut newValue)
    {
        if (_cache.ContainsKey(key))
            _cache[key] = newValue;
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        _cache.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered an [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)?

Comment: @Igor, you mean to resolve the conflict of Add() and Remove() between the two interfaces? That would help, but that's not my main concern here. I'd just like to avoid making another caching class for the IProcessorComposite interface. Or do explicit interface implementations help with that too?

Comment: Yes, that was specific to resolving the interface conflict. If the caching strategy is generic you could implement a solution based on AOP. DI frameworks like [AutoFac](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html) support this. You could use attributes to mark methods where you want your caching code to execute.

Comment: That sounds interesting, I'll definitely look into it!